# ipython %%javascript magic output into cell and console

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, console.log

How to adjust ipythons' `%%javascript` cell magic so that it 
outputs both to output cell of ipython and to console of the browser as shown below[image: cellmagic]

I don't want to use `alert()`. Furthermore, I tried to get similar behavior with nodejs using `%%script` magic

```
%%script node
console.log("Hi")
```

But this is not what I need.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you have access to the output Dom node under the variable named `element` wrapped in jquery. So:

```
%%javascript
element.text('Hi')
console.log('There')
```

Comment: when I try to use it twice ( `element.text('Hi') element.text('Bye')` ) it just outputs the last one.

Comment: As stated in the answer element is an already existing  dom node. Using [`.text(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) does replace the inner text, but that's DOM api. You need to use Dom manipulataion API to [create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) new elments and [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) them  to the one you have access to. But that's "how to build HTML from javascript" which is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Note that element is via jQuery, and `element.html('Hi')` is also available -- and is much more flexible in terms of passing in formatted output (e.g. multilines with `br`, markup etc.

Answer (score 3):

Just came across this which got me part of the way there but as noted if you use only element.text() you only get the last one.  But you can use element.append() repeatedly in the same cell with the %%javascript and and all of the output will go to the following cell.  Just make sure to append a <br> if you want a carriage return.  Like for example

```
function assert(cond,msg)
{
   if (!cond)
   {
     element.append(msg + "<br>");
   }
}
```